# sbt unable to locate gatling simulation

Tags: docker, scala, jenkins, sbt, gatling

I am trying to invoke sbt gatling:testOnly org.mygrpcTest through executor.sh being invoked through Jenkins (docker). Tried with sbt "gatling:testOnly org.mygrpcTest" and "sbt gatling:test org.mygrpcTest"  but these also do not work.

Just to note the same thing works fine on windows when executed locally using IntelliJ.

Upon enabling debug flag I can see that its possibly unable to locate the source. The way I have structured the code is as per sbt documentation and being a newbie with SBT and gatling I am unsure if I am missing something very basic here.
With the debug flag for sbt I can see that all sbt/gatling dependencies are indeed getting resolved correctly.
Can someone help here to guide what could I be missing here? Here is brief debug output--

```
[debug] [zinc] IncrementalCompile -----------
[debug] IncrementalCompile.incrementalCompile
[debug] previous = Stamps for: 0 products, 0 sources, 0 libraries
[debug] current source = Set()
[debug] > initialChanges = InitialChanges(Changes(added = Set(), removed = Set(), changed = Set(), unmodified = ...),Set(),Set(),API Changes: Set())
[debug] Full compilation, no sources in previous analysis.
```